# pandas replace nan multiple fields with another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace some nan fields in the first dataframe with another dataframe.
first dataframe like this:

```
data={'month':['2021-10','2021-11','2021-12','2022-01','2021-02'],
      'sessions':[10000,25000,32684,7415,None],
      'users':[2500,3600,4120,2154,None],
      'new_users':[750,840,980,874,680],
       'cr':[1.2,0.9,0.7,None,0.78}
df1=pd.DataFrame(data)

df1
month    sessions   users   new_users   cr
2021-10  10000      2500    750         1.2
2021-11  25000      3600    840         0.9
2021-12  32684      4120    980         0.7
2022-01  7415       2154    974         nan
2022-02  nan        nan     680         0.78
```

df2:

```
data2={'month':['2021-12','2022-01','2021-02'],
      'sessions':[32684,7415,4122],
      'users':[4120,3650,4120]
      'cr':[0.7,0.85,0.78]}
df2=pd.DataFrame(data2)

df2
month    sessions   users   cr
2021-12  32684      4120    0.7
2022-01  7415       3650    0.85
2022-02  4122       4120    0.78
```

expected output:

```
month    sessions   users   new_users  cr
2021-10  10000      2500    750        1.2
2021-11  25000      3600    840        0.9
2021-12  32684      4120    980        0.7
2022-01  7415       2154    974        0.85
2022-02  4122       4120    680        0.78
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) and [`reindex_like`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_like.html) to keep the same order:

```
d = df1.set_index('month')

df1 = (d
 .combine_first(df2.set_index('month'))
 .reindex_like(d).reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
     month  sessions   users  new_users    cr
0  2021-10   10000.0  2500.0        750  1.20
1  2021-11   25000.0  3600.0        840  0.90
2  2021-12   32684.0  4120.0        980  0.70
3  2022-01    7415.0  2154.0        874  0.85
4  2021-02    4122.0  4120.0        680  0.78
```

Comment: second dupe match for 100% like your answer.

Comment: Is it normal to have more than one month in the month column ?

Comment: @Clegane I don't understand your remark, can you clarify?

Comment: After the last edit you made, the dataframe looks correct, but the nan fields are still nan. I checked the question and didn't see any mistakes. Is there anything else you can suggest ?

Comment: @Clegane please provide a reproducible example where you have the NaNs

Comment: @mozway New dataframe comes same as df1. Your answer works for the data in the question. Most likely my question is wrong. I'll try to edit the question.

Comment: @mozway The first dataframe's month column is of type object, while the second dataframe's month column is of type period[M]. Everything is perfect now, thank you so much.

Comment: @Clegane great! Yes, types need to match for index alignment ;)